# How to fix indentation of comments before } else { in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, comments, text-editor, indentation

Here is a typical example:

```
// Testing expression
if (expression) {

  method();

  // All other options
} else {

  otherMethod();

}
```

The second comment is, I believe, wrongly (too naively) tabulated by the Visual Studio editor as it assumes it is intended for the first block.

Currently, my indenting is set to Smart and setting it to Block will not allow restructuring (auto-indenting) if the code is contained inside a new pair of brackets.

How can this behaviour be corrected so that comments at the very end of blocks get indented according to the following block ?

Comment: Delete the extra tab? BTW - doesn't look wrong to me. The comment starts just above the `else`.

Comment: it thinks that comment is in the previous code block because it is inside the closing curly brace for the `if`. IMO, it's working correctly because it assumes you use C# standard code style.

Comment: what do you mean it's wrongly tabbed? It's at the same tab distance as the `method()` call

Comment: Highlight the code block then Edit menu > Advanced > Format Selection

Comment: There's little point in arguing style, but that comment *really* belongs inside the else {} body.  Well, I think so and so did the IDE team.  You have the Delete key to enforce your own style.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what is and isn't in scope. Everything inside of brackets are the same scope so have the same indentation level. IE the editor is doing exactly what it is designed to do. If you want the comment to have the same level of indentation, have it in the same scope. Here is an example where the comment would have the same indentation level as the else because they share the same scope. I altered the placement of the brackets to follow the more standard formatting used in code:

```
      //First option:
      if (expression)
      {
        method();
      }
      // All other options (This is the same scope as if above and else below)
      else
      {
        otherMethod();
      }
```